# Redirect after submit has been done using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Im working on a progress status bar for a form... you can see a an example here:
http://www.enteratenorte.org/app-example/exa/

This is what I have so far:

The **css** is:

```
<style>
body { padding: 30px }
form { display: block; margin: 20px auto; background: #eee; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px }
.progress { position:relative; width:652px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
.bar { width:0%; height:40px; border-radius: 3px; background-image:url('loader.gif')}
.percent { line-height:35px; color:#fff; position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #009303, -2px 0 0 #009303, 0 2px 0 #009303, 0 -2px 0 #009303, 1px 1px #009303, -1px -1px 0 #009303, 1px -1px 0 #009303, -1px 1px 0 #009303; }
</style>
```

The **HTML** code is:

```
<h1>File Upload Progress Demo #1</h1>
        <form action="zip-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
    </form>

    <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div >
        <div class="percent">0%</div >
    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>
```

The **Script** goes like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function() {

    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        success: function() {
            var percentVal = '100%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }); 

    })();       
    </script>
```

and the **PHP in the Receiver** file is:

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    } else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"temp/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      chmod("temp/". $_FILES["file"]["name"], 0777);
      rename("temp/". $_FILES["file"]["name"], "temp/mynewfile.jpg");
      echo "Image successfully uploaded";     
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "File doesn't match the requiere criteria";
  }
```

Everything is working perfectly. The problem is, when if finishes uploading, it only displays que "Image successfully uploaded", but I would like to redirect the form to a different page, how can this be done?

Also, progress bar works with Safari, Firefox and Chrome... surprisingly (I'm being sarcastic) it doesn't work in IE, it uploads but progress bar doesn't move until the file has been completely uploaded and it does displays the "Image successfully uploaded"

Can some one help me with the redirect option, if not too much abuse of assistance
, also see what IE. :D

Comment: Has this question been answered to your satisfaction? If not, please post additional information about what you need. Else, please close the question by either: choosing a correct answer, or write your own solution and select that as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understand your question correctly and am answering the right question... Off the top of my head, there are at least three ways to redirect:

PHP:

```
header("Location: pagename.php");
```

HTML:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5; url=pagename.php">
```

The PHP header() method is preferred, but will not work if other headers (or html) were previously output to page. As a work-around, you can use this method to redirect the page, and the bonus is that it will wait the specified number of seconds before doing so (5 in this case, or zero if you choose).

JS:

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.com';  // or just 'pagename.php';
```

Comment: The meta refresh would be for the HTML file, but there is no way of knowing how much time it would take to upload, so it not what I need...

Comment: The JS could work, in the `complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }` area, but the responseText could be that the file didn't upload correctly, so is there a way in redirecting depending on the reponse??

Comment: Yes. First, you need to capture/predict the response. You should be able to do that using `console.log(xhr.responseText)` a few times, or even `alert()`. Then use an if statement, yes? If that won't work, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

For the redirect, you can just use `header`:

`header('Location:<URL>');`

But you need to remove the 'image sucessfully loaded' echo, header won't work if anything has been output before it.